# java api REST client for POST ERROR: no suitable HttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring, rest, api

I use Maven + Spring and I want use `RestTemplate().postForEntity(url, request, responseType)` + `Content-Type=application/json`
but I have this error:

**org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [com.kizeoforms.model.User] and content type [application/json]**

java REST client code:

```
User user = new User();
user.setUser("foo");
user.setPassword("**********");
user.setCompany("xxxxxx");

MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
HttpEntity<User> request = new HttpEntity<User>(user, headers);
ResponseEntity<Object> response = new RestTemplate().postForEntity("https://www.kizeoforms.com:443/rest/v3/login", request, Object.class);
System.out.println(response.getStatusCode());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had `new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter()` to `restTemplate`:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
ResponseEntity<Object> response = restTemplate.postForEntity("https://www.kizeoforms.com:443/rest/v3/login", request, Object.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [Restemplate](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.java#L140) constructor, if there are supported serialized packaged included in your project, the corresponding message converters will be added. So you can add a dependency package, such as `com.google.gson.Gson` or `javax.json.bind.Jsonb`, then you needn't handle the message converts explicitly.